# How to average multiple non-normal distributions?

Tags: distributions, quantiles, convolution

I have the following statistics of two independent random variables:

First random variable:

```
size: 3830
mean: 119240
percentile 10: 61750
percentile 25: 79930
median: 118250
percentile 75: 145950
percentile 90: 174840
```

Second random variable:

```
size: 5290
mean: 153180
percentile 10: 81180
percentile 25: 124860
median: 159310
percentile 75: 169090
percentile 90: 192860
```

How can I estimate the percentiles of a third independent random variable by averaging the two above random variables?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining distribution stats of multiple populations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/601662/combining-distribution-stats-of-multiple-populations)

Answer (score 0):

I assume by the average of the two random variables, you mean the distribution of the mean of random variables with those distributions.

Let the distributions have cdf's $F$ and $G$.  Let $q$ be the $100p$'s percentile of that distribution
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}} \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
\P(\frac{X+Y}{2}\le q )=p$$
leading to
\begin{align}
p &= \int \P(X \le 2q-Y \mid Y=y) f_Y(y) \; dy \\
  &= \int \P(X \le 2q-y) \; dy \\  
  &= \int F_X(2q-y) f(y) \; dy \\
  &= \E_Y F_X(2q-Y)
\end{align}
but that equation will have an explicit solution only in special cases.

But first you will need to approximate $F$ and $G$ from the quantiles you have.

Comment: Thanks! I am not a statistician, so I have difficulty to implement your solution. Is it possible for you to add a numeric example?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the two original datasets, I recommend aggregating $5290$ copies of the first population and $500$ copies of the second population to get a new dataset with $3830\times 5290+500\times 5290=22\,905\,700$ datapoints. You can estimate the percentiles from that.

If you don't have the two original datasets, you'll have to guess. If we call the given percentiles $q$ (for quantile), we might try the assumption that each pdf is a piecewise-linear function between the points $(q_0,0)$, $(q_{10},f_{10})$, $(q_{25},f_{25})$, $(q_{50},f_{50})$, $(q_{75},f_{75})$, $(q_{90},f_{90})$, $(q_{100},0)$, and zero elsewhere. We can calculate the mean and the six areas separated by those five percentiles in terms of $q_0, f_{10}, f_{25}, f_{50}, f_{75}, f_{90}, q_{100}$, and solve the resulting seven equations for the seven variables.

A reasonable solution would have $q_0\le q_{10}\le q_{90}\le q_{100}$ and $\min(f_{10},f_{25},f_{50},f_{75},f_{90})\ge0$. The first dataset has exactly one reasonable solution. By contrast, the second dataset is so highly spiked between the 50th and 75th percentiles that it has no reasonable solutions of this form. (See update below.) But there is one solution for the second data set satisfying the inequalities on the $q$'s, and we can work with the negative $f$'s. Here are the graphs of the two piecewise-linear functions, scaled up by 3830 and 500 to give approximate formal histograms for the two datasets.

[image]

Obviously the orange graph goes negative and is not a reasonable histogram! We can still plot the sum of the two graphs, and fortunately the result is positive from 46286 to 498411, and a plausible-looking histogram for the mixture.

[image]

Similarly, using the combined pdf of (3830/4330) times the first function plus (500/4330) times the second function, we can estimate the quantiles of the mixture as:

- 10th quantile: $\ \,$62780
- 25th quantile: $\ \,$83090
- 50th quantile: 120350
- 75th quantile: 153520
- 90th quantile: 178910

Perhaps these estimates, even if calculated via some not-very-meaningful negative numbers, are good enough for your purposes.

Perhaps fitting the data to a wider class of models would be better, even with more difficult calculations and maybe arbitrary choices between multiple solutions.

Or perhaps a simple calculation with 23 million datapoints looks pretty good.

**Update:** By examining average pdfs over three regions, we can prove that reasonable models of this type can not fit the second dataset. In this model
$$\frac{f_{25}+f_{50}}{\phantom{1}2^{\phantom{2}}}=\frac{\int_{q_{25}}^{q_{50}}f(x)dx}{q_{50}-q_{25}}=\frac{0.50-0.25}{q_{50}-q_{25}}$$
and similarly for other pairs of neighboring quantiles. So
a reasonable solution would satisfy
$$\frac{f_{25}+f_{50}}{2}+\frac{f_{75}+f_{90}}{2}\ge \frac{f_{50}+f_{75}}{2}$$
and
$$\frac{0.50-0.25}{q_{50}-q_{25}}+
\frac{0.90-0.75}{q_{90}-q_{75}}\ge
\frac{0.75-0.50}{q_{75}-q_{50}}$$
But in this case that would give
$$\frac{7.3}{10^6}+\frac{6.3}{10^6}\ge\frac{25.6}{10^6}$$
which is false.

Comment: I don't follow how you derive those "histograms". What evidence suggests that either of these populations are bimodally distributed? I don't see how you infer that from the list of percentile values.

Comment: That initial recommendation is computational overkill.  Just give each element of the first population a weight of the *second* population's count and *vice versa,* then report the weighted quantiles in the combined dataset.  With two (sorted) batches of data of sizes $n_1$ and $n_2$ this is a $O(n_1+n_2)$ operation compared to your $O(n_1n_2)$ proposal and it will give exactly the same values.  Because both sets of statistics use the same quantiles, you don't need to solve any equations: a simple linear interpolation among each pair of quantiles will work fine.

Comment: @whuber, that's the way I think about it too, but I often avoid talking about weighted quantiles because I find that they confuse many people who could use them -- and neither Excel nor base R has built-in functions for weighted quantiles.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie, the first dataset must be multimodal because the average pdf is 8.25/10^6 between the 10th and 25th percentiles, 6.52/10^6 between the 25th and 50th percentiles, and 9.03/10^6 between the 50th and 75th percentiles.

Comment: Yes, but here the OP explicitly refers to combining just a few thousand values as "computationally heavy," so it makes little sense to recommend a procedure that takes a thousand times longer!

Comment: I interpreted the OP as saying that generating another 500 values would be computationally heavy (and implying that they didn't see how to avoid that).