# Combining distribution stats of multiple populations

Tags: distributions, quantiles

I have the following statistics of two independent populations:

First population:

```
size: 3830
mean: 119240
percentile 10: 61750
percentile 25: 79930
median: 118250
percentile 75: 145950
percentile 90: 174840
```

Second population:

```
size: 5290
mean: 153180
percentile 10: 81180
percentile 25: 124860
median: 159310
percentile 75: 169090
percentile 90: 192860
```

I want to add a sample set from the second population (Say 500 data points) to the first population and recalculate the percentiles. I know I can do it by simulating data and combine them but it's computationally heavy for my case. I am not looking for the exact percentiles, but just an approximation.